# MobX computed function not working

Tags: react-native, momentjs, mobx

I have a user:

```
@observable user = {name: 'john', birth_date: 1523020350, [...};
```

and a computed function:

```
@computed get userBirthdayString() {
    return moment(this.user.birth_date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
}
```

I'm using the computed function like this:

```
<Text>Birthday: {this.userBirthdayString}</Text>
```

and it's not working.

Previously I was declaring it like this:

```
    @observable userBirthdayString = moment(this.user.birth_date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

and doing this `autorun` in componentWillMount:

```
autorun(() => this.userBirthdayString = moment(this.user.birth_date).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
```

and that works just fine but I read autorun shouldn't be used like that.

Have I set up the computed incorrectly?  Should I continue to use the autorun?

Thanks!

Comment: _"it's not working"_ is not a problem description. Why not? What should happen? What happens instead?

Comment: is your component an `observer`?

Comment: Yep. All my observables and the auto runs are working fine.

Comment: Where are you using this `userBirthdayString` i had the experience computed works fine in render() fucnctions but you shouldn't use them inside actions or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not react related at all but to momentjs/your miliseconds:

```
moment(1523020350).format() == "1970-01-18T16:03:40+01:00"
moment(1523020350000).format() == "2018-04-06T15:12:30+02:00"
```

Instead of using milliseconds till epoch you might have used seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Might be more useful if we saw the whole component. What is your default state? How does `birth_date` get changed? Looks like you are storing state locally instead of in a store which is fine. What you're doing should work. Is `birth_date` added dynamically to `user`? MobX won't like that.